# How to turn visual studio files into actual app that can be sent/ downloaded and run by another user?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have a finished project with a bunch of different winform files. They are linked between eachother through a menu file. How do I go from having this project as a visual studio application file to an actual application, with customized icon and that can be opened by a user from another PC (which doesn't have Visual studio). I don't want to just zip them.

I didn't try anything and this might be a newbie question but what I expect is basically to have an actual app instead of a bunch of files.

Comment: You're talking about "publishing" your app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile the winforms project you get a bin folder and a Debug/Release folders inside.
A simple way to deliver the app is just copy the Debug folder that have the .exe and dll files to the dest PC.
The best way is to follow this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2022
Or make an autoinstaller